# Anaconda ModuleNotFoundError with custom package installed using pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, spyder

Im running Anaconda3 on windows 10 and installed a custom package using

```
C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\Scripts\pip install mypackage
```

So this command installed the package inside

```
C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mypackage
```

If I start the **Anaconda prompt** and run

```
conda activate myenv
python
>> import mypackage
```

I get no problem whatsoever, but inside Spyder, Im getting **ModuleNotFoundError**

**Anaconda prompt**

```
conda activate myenv
python
>> import sys; sys.executable
 'C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\python.exe'

>> import os; os.environ['PATH']
'C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\condabin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32'
```

**Spyder**

```
In[8]: import sys; sys.executable
Out[8]: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\pythonw.exe'    


In[13]: import os; os.environ['PATH']
Out[13]:'C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\condabin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32;C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32'
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Could you also post the results of `import os; os.environ['PATH']` that you get from the Anaconda prompt and our IPython console? Thanks!

Comment: Done, I've added the PATH variables on the post